# how can join a query result set with an existing table?

Tags: sql, mysql

is there any way to avoid using tmp table?

I am using a query with aggregate function (sum) to generate the sum of each product: 
the result looks like this:

```
product_name | sum(qty) 
product_1    | 100 
product_2    | 200 
product_5    | 300
```

now i want to join the above result to another table called products. 
so that i will have a summary like this:

```
product_name | sum(qty) 
product_1    | 100 
product_2    | 200 
product_3    | 0 
product_4    | 0 
product_5    | 300
```

i know 1 way of doing this is the dump the 1st query result to a temp table then join it with products table. is there a better way?

Comment: Could you please provide some examples so we can help?

Comment: I am using a query with aggregate function (sum) to generate the sum of each product:
the result looks like this:

 product_name | sum(qty)
 product_1    | 100
 product_2    | 200
 product_5    | 300

now i want to join the above result to another table called products. so that i will have a summary like this:
product_name | sum(qty)
product_1    | 100
product_2    | 200
product_3    | 0
product_4    | 0
product_5    | 300
i know 1 way of doing this is the dump the 1st query result to a temp table then join it with products table. is there a better way?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
SELECT Product_Name, Total FROM ProductTable x
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SUM(qty) as Total, ProductID FROM InventoryTable 
    GROUP BY ProductID) y
ON x.ProductID = y.ProductID
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this

```
select table1.productname, virtualtable.qty
from table1 
inner join (
  select productid, qty
  from table2
  group by productid
) as virtualtable on virtualtable.productid = table1.productid
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the UNION syntax is what you are looking for? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html
Some more information would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple joins in one `select` query. Does that solve your problem? It's hard to tell what you are asking for.